# how to create slideshow of dynamic imageviews in android?

Tags: android, android-imageview

I am working on application in which I need to fetch pictures from gallery and display those into dynamic ImageViews. I am successful doing this, but now I have to create a slide show with the pictures fetched from gallery. How can I do this?

Here is my code:

```
LinearLayout lLayout;
Bitmap yourSelectedImage;
int flag=1;
ImageView slidingimage;
int imageId=1;
int imageindex=1;

int i=0;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    createLayout();


}

public void createLayout(){

    LinearLayout parentLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.Playout);
       lLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
        lLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);


        LinearLayout.LayoutParams myLayoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        myLayoutParams.leftMargin = 0;
        //myLayoutParams.topMargin = 50 * i;
        myLayoutParams.width = 480;
        myLayoutParams.height = 150;

        lLayout.setLayoutParams(myLayoutParams);

        parentLayout.addView(lLayout);


        btn1 = new Button(this); 
        btn1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.add);
        //btn1.setId(i);



        LinearLayout.LayoutParams rel_btn = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

            /*rel_btn.leftMargin = 150;
            rel_btn.topMargin = myYPosition;*/
            rel_btn.width = 160;
            rel_btn.height = 150;

            btn1.setLayoutParams(rel_btn);

            lLayout.addView(btn1);
            btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // Perform action on click   

                    Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
                    photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
                    startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, 1);


                }
            });


}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, 
           Intent imageReturnedIntent) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, imageReturnedIntent); 

        switch(requestCode) { 
        case 1:
            if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){  
                Uri selectedImage = imageReturnedIntent.getData();
                String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};

                Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(
                                   selectedImage, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
                cursor.moveToFirst();

                int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
                String filePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                cursor.close();
                yourSelectedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath);

                ImageView img = new ImageView(this);
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams parms = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(160,150);
                img.setLayoutParams(parms);
                img.setId(imageId);

                imageId++;
                img.setImageBitmap(yourSelectedImage);
                lLayout.addView(img, 0);
                flag++;

                if(flag>3){

                    btn1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    createLayout();
                    flag=1;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a list of all images you have fetched and then display them in the imageview or the  listview,whatever you desire.......

```
 ArrayList<Bitmap/or drawable (you choose)> variable1=null;

create a loop
for(till all images are fetched............)
{

Bitmap/Drawable variable2=new Bitmap/Drawable();
variable2=your image from gallery;
variable1.add(variable2);
}
```

all images have been fetched now and are contained in a list(variable1)....
display them 1 by 1 or however you would like to............

Comment: thanks for ur help but won't that take up an aweful lot of memory?

Comment: yeah it will,sorry for that....well if you are working with a few images,you can use it..
if you are working with the whole gallery....you can use mediastore....
mediastore has the database of all the files and it is updated on each start up of the device...
you can create the list of all paths of images(and not the image itself,hence dealing with the memory problem)and then display them one by one....
instead of using "Bitmap var............"
use "String var...." and store only the path. in the list..(rest of the code remains the same)

Comment: when you want to display the image,fetch the image from the path  and display it...and reuse the same variable to store the image,so that you don't have to worry about the memory.........